# Javascript - How to get last record from array list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an array list and and I want only last record from the array list, how to get that?[image: array list]

I want message(i.e. Hey) from last record of this array.

**here is my code:**

```
let chats : any = [];

  items.forEach((item) =>
  {
    if(item.val().sent_by == loggedInUserKey && item.val().sent_to == UserKey)
    {
      chats.push({
        key              : item.key,
        sent_by          : item.val().sent_by,
        sent_to          : item.val().sent_to,
        message          : item.val().message,
        datetime         : item.val().datetime
      });
    }
    if(item.val().sent_to == loggedInUserKey && item.val().sent_by == UserKey)
    {
      chats.push({
        key              : item.key,
        sent_by          : item.val().sent_by,
        sent_to          : item.val().sent_to,
        message          : item.val().message,
        datetime         : item.val().datetime
      });
    }
  });
  this.chats = chats;
  var last = chats[chats.length - 1];
  console.log("last: ",last);
  console.log("Chats : ",this.chats);
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add code not image...

Comment: you want `angular html template` or just `javascript` code to access last record?

Comment: Duplicate of duplicate!

Comment: @NamanKheterpal just javascript

Comment: @Zich Tried it already

Comment: @Mamun I don't know the code

Comment: doesn't `Chats[Chats.length - 1].message` this work?

Comment: @Mamun it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lastMessage = chats[chats.length - 1].message;
console.log(lastMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks. worked it. :)

Answer (score 6):

You could just use `array.length-1` to find the last value. I'll include a code snippet demonstration below:

```js
const myArrayList = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu'];

console.log(myArrayList[myArrayList.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `array[array.length - 1]`

Example:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var lastVal = array[array.length - 1];

console.log(lastVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write something like this:

```
someArray[someArray.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative indexes to access elements from last as:

```
var last = myArray[-1]
```

Comment: It is displaying "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

If you are purely interested in the last element of a JavaScript Array you can use .pop()

```js
var arr = ['first', 'second', 'last'];
var item = arr.pop();
console.log('accessed item: ', item);
```